# Is it possible to create that query using Spring Data with mongoDB?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-repositories

like in question is it possible to create that query?

```
db.persons.find({ 'oi': '5f2417e3c655cb13e85186df', 'ch': { $elemMatch: { 'type': { $in: ['MAN']  }}}}, {'ch.$': 1})
```

The last part of this query is problematic. How to retrive fields that pass the $elemMatch predicate only.
Spring data @Query annotation have field property but if specify it by `{'children: 1'}` I retrive all children instead of this which pass the query.
`{ 'children.$': 1}` doesn't work of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Query` annotation. Pass the query in value and projection in fields inside `@Query` annotation like this

```
@Query(value = "{ 'oi': ?0, 'ch': { $elemMatch: { 'type': { $in: ?1 }}}}", fields = "{'ch.$' : 1}")
Person findPersonCustom(String id, List<String> types);
```

Here `?0` & `?1` will be passed as method arguments 0 & 1 respectively. You can also put that values inside `@Query` directly if they are static.

The resulted `Person` object will contain only matched elements from `ch` array.

Comment: That is not true. It will contains all array.

Comment: It actually works, I am using spring boot 2.1.5 with mongodb 4.0 and it works. There may be something wrong with code or field names. Can you post the code with which you have tried?

Comment: also turn on logging to see query using `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG`

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible to pass positional operator to fields value ?

Comment: Yes I am sure as I have used these type of queries in my project and it works